# Get substring from string using start and end white spaced position

Tags: java, string

I have a string and I wanted to get the substring based on the start and end position of the words.

I have written it and it works fine, but I wanted to know if there is a clean way using any library to acheive the same

```
                    String keyword = "My test string value"
                    int start = 1;
                    int end = 2;
                    String[] arr = keyword.split("\\s+");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
                        sb.append(arr[i]).append(" ");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim(); // returns "test string"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about any libraries, but you could replace

```
String[] arr = keyword.split("\\s+");
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
     sb.append(arr[i]).append(" ");
 }
 return sb.toString().trim();
```

with

```
 return Arrays.stream(keyword.split("\\s+"))
        .limit(end+1)
        .skip(start)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```